# Get value from nested collection (LINQ)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I have LINQ expression with `Include`, and several `ThenInclude`

Here is code

```
var test2 =  Loanapplications.Include(x=> x.LoanApplicationPositions)
.ThenInclude(x => x.PositionPlayterinvoices)
.ThenInclude(x=> x.PlayterInvoiceLoanpaymentagreements)
.Include(x => x.RecruitmentAgencyClient.Client)
.Select(x => new
{
    LoanId = x.LoanApplicationPositions.Select(x=> x.PositionPlayterinvoices),
```

I need to get LoanId which is under `.ThenInclude(x=> x.PlayterInvoiceLoanpaymentagreements)`

How I can get this?

Comment: It would help to show the classes and also the entire end result you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that your models look like this

```
class LoanApplication{
public List<LoanApplicationPosition> LoanApplicationPositions{get;set;}
}

class LoanApplicationPosition{
public List<PositionPlayterInvoce> PositionPlayterinvoices{get;set;}
}

class PositionPlayterInvoce{
public List<PlayterInvoiceLoanpaymentagreement> PlayterInvoiceLoanpaymentagreements{get;set;}
}
```

If that is correct then you need to:

- choose one LoanApplicationPosition from that list
- choose one PositionPlayterInvoce from the list of PositionPlayterinvoices
- choose one PlayterInvoiceLoanpaymentagreement from the list of PlayterInvoiceLoanpaymentagreements

Something like this

```
var l = x.LoanApplicationPositions.FirstOrDefault();
var t = l.PositionPlayterinvoices.FirstOrDefault();
var LoanId = t.PlayterInvoiceLoanpaymentagreements.FirstOrDefault().LoanId
```

Comment: That's a very inefficient way to get only one Id value from the database.

Comment: GertArnold You are right but I would assume that he is going to get more than that id from chunk of data

Comment: That's why I've gradually learned not to answer from assumptions and to wait until the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have custom projection, `Select` in you case, Includes are completely ignored. So you have to write query yourself:

```cs
var query = 
    from la in Loanapplications
    from lap in la.LoanApplicationPositions
    from ppi in lap.PositionPlayterinvoices
    from pila in ppi.PlayterInvoiceLoanpaymentagreements
    select pila.LoadId;
```

Comment: can I inject this query to `test` variable Select?

Comment: And I need Select only loan Id , that has LoanApplicationId

Comment: I do not see your model classes. Update question. If you need correct LINQ query - post your model.